# Facebook unable to read open graph tags generated by nextjs

Tags: facebook-opengraph, next.js

Everything is in this url:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fweally.org%2Fentity%2F5dcac229156b765cb8c45148%2Fissue%2F5dcac2085b0a145d1f08d16e

If you go to the page facebook is testing and lookup the source code, the meta tags are present (they are even duplicated, but that's another issue)
https://weally.org/entity/5dcac229156b765cb8c45148/issue/5dcac2085b0a145d1f08d16e

here's my _document.js file : I tried to enforce the tags on the first load in ssr

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, {Head, Main, NextScript} from 'next/document';
import {ServerStyleSheets} from '@material-ui/styles';
import theme from '../src/theme';
import {getIssueImageSrc} from "../src/utils/util";
import DeveloperError from "../src/error/DeveloperError";

const ISSUE_URL_PREFIX = '/entity/';

function isIssuePath(path) {
    return !path.startsWith(ISSUE_URL_PREFIX) && path.indexOf('/issue/') != -1
}

function getIssueIdFromPath(path) {

    const startIndex = path.indexOf('/issue/') + '/issue/'.length
    let otherParam = path.indexOf('/', startIndex);
    if (otherParam == -1) otherParam = path.length

    const issueId = path.substr(startIndex, otherParam - startIndex)
    console.log("issue id for paht ", path, "   is : ", issueId)
    return issueId
}

class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (<html lang="en">
        <Head>
            <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
            {/* Use minimum-scale=1 to enable GPU rasterization */}
            <meta
                    name="viewport"
                    content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"
            />
            {/* PWA primary color */}
            <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main}/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>
            <link
                    rel="stylesheet"
                    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
            />
            {this.props.desc && <meta property="og:description" content={this.props.desc}/>}
            {this.props.desc == null && <meta property="og:description"
                                                                                content="Make your complaint about any company visible to the entire world on WeAlly.org. We can finally look at the problems companies have with their customers, complain on WeAlly and join the responsible citizens"/>}
            {this.props.image && <meta property="og:description" content={this.props.image}/>}
            {this.props.image == null && <meta property="og:image" content={'https://weally.org/static/images/fb_splash.jpg'}/>}
            {this.props.title && <meta property="og:title" content={this.props.title}/>}
            {this.props.title == null && <meta property="og:title" content="Allied together, our complaints are powerful"/>}

            <link rel="icon" href="/static/images/favicon.ico"/>
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/scripts.js">
            </script>
            <meta property="og:url" content={`https://weally.org`}/>
            <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>

        </Head>
        <body>
        <Main/>
        <NextScript/>
        </body>
        </html>);
    }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    // Resolution order
    //
    // On the server:
    // 1. app.getInitialProps
    // 2. page.getInitialProps
    // 3. document.getInitialProps
    // 4. app.render
    // 5. page.render
    // 6. document.render
    //
    // On the server with error:
    // 1. document.getInitialProps
    // 2. app.render
    // 3. page.render
    // 4. document.render
    //
    // On the client
    // 1. app.getInitialProps
    // 2. page.getInitialProps
    // 3. app.render
    // 4. page.render

    // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
    const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: App => props => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    const metaTags = {}

    if (!process.browser) {
        const path = ctx.asPath
        if (path.startsWith(ISSUE_URL_PREFIX)) {
            try {
                const issueId = getIssueIdFromPath(path)
                const mongoose = require('mongoose')
                const Complaint = mongoose.model('Complaint')
                const complaint = await Complaint.findById(issueId)

                metaTags.image = getIssueImageSrc(complaint)
                metaTags.desc = complaint.desc
                metaTags.title = complaint.title

            } catch (e) {
                console.log( "Error in meta data prefetching ", e )
            }
        }
    }

    const propsToReturn = {
        ...metaTags,
        ...initialProps, // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
        styles: (<React.Fragment>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheets.getStyleElement()}
        </React.Fragment>),
    }

    return propsToReturn
}


export default MyDocument;
```

I naturally double checked, that the tags are inserted by this code, and they are.

Any ideas please, facebook is always falling back to the "default values" that are not relevant at all for that kind of urls. Also notice that facebook debugger is complaining about og:image that he doesn't seem to see at all

Comment: It is fetching `https://weally.org/` and tries to get the meta data from there, because _you_ specified that as the `og:url`.

Comment: Ah!!! ok cool, I'll try to fix that and get back to you, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I published a new version where the url is put, but it seams next.js is putting the default url once before I can put the right one. And facebook takes the first one

Comment: I still see only one version of `og:url` in the source code of the URL you mentioned.

Comment: Yes you're right I saw that, I removed it.

Now things work but facebook is still complaining: Missing Properties
The following required properties are missing: og:url

and the property is obviously there

Comment: It is not in the page _source code_ - and that is all Facebook cares about. Anything that tries to set OG meta tags via client-side scripting, gets completely ignored.

Comment: You can ignore the warning though (if putting `og:url` directly into the initial HTML source code is not a valid option), it should not prevent this from working, as long as the rest of the info is present in the HTML markup.

Comment: yes I know that facebook falls back to defaults, I'm just afraid taht since they write it is a required field, they stop falling back in future versions. Thanks for your help 04FS